# Guess the arithmetical function based on its Riemann zeta form

Tags: number-theory

Define the arithmetical function $\tau_k $by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tau_k(n)}{n^s}= \zeta(s)^k$$

Obtain a number theoretic interpretation for $ \tau_k(n) $ ie, it is the number of $...$ what?

I realize i want something like $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n^s})^k= \zeta(s)^k$$ or something similar in the prime form but i have no idea what this is? Please help.

Comment: If you use product form of zeta, it becomes obvious.

Comment: i did try using $$\Pi_{p} (\frac {1}{1-p^{-s}})^k$$ already? if thats what you mean i just see no reason why it has anything to do with n?

Comment: @Faust Use series by the Binomial theorem.

Comment: you need two terms for that to make sense don't you $(x+y)^k$ not just $(x+0)^k $ ?

Comment: my best guess it that its just all the primes that divide n to the power k.

Comment: @Faust I meant with a power of $-k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the algebra of Dirichlet's series
$$ \zeta(s)^k = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1*1*\ldots*1(n)}{n^s} $$
where $1(n)$ is the function which constantly equals $1$, 
$$ (1*1)(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} 1 = d(n)=\tau(n)=\prod_{p^k\parallel n}(k+1), $$
$$ (1*1*1)(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \tau(d) = \prod_{p^k\parallel n}\sum_{d\mid p^k}\tau(d)=\prod_{p^k\parallel n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(j+1)=\prod_{p^k\parallel n}\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}=\frac{\tau(n)\,\tau(n\,\text{rad}(n))}{2^{\omega(n)}} $$
$$ (1*1*1*1)(n) = \prod_{p^k\parallel n}\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{6}=\frac{\tau(n)\,\tau(n\,\text{rad} n)\,\tau(n\,\text{rad}^2 n)}{6^{\omega(n)}} $$

and so on. We exploited the fact that the Dirichlet convolution is associative and the fact that if $f$ is a multiplicative function, $(1*f)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$ is also a multiplicative function.

Comment: so your claiming that ] $ \tau_k(n) = (1* \cdots * 1)(n)$ k times? whats the interpretation of this?

Comment: @Faust: the only possible one - the multiple Dirichlet convolution of $1(n)$ with itself.

Comment: with itself or with 1? cause it looks like you did it with 1?

Comment: @Faust: the convolution between $1$ and itself means the convolution between $1$ and $1$, there is no discrepancy here.